# Cómo hago para que mi MainWindow en PyQt5 se estire, dependiendo de la resolución?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Soy nuevo en esto de PyQt5, actualmente estoy usando QtDesigner, pero quiero hacer que mi MainWindow quedé a la resolución de la computadora que lo abra, además que los widgets también se ajusten y quede todo bien centrado,lo que pasa es que cuando hago una interfaz, yo la veo bien, pero cuando la abro en otra computadora con una resolución mucho más baja, se corta la mainwindow y no se ve completa, el showMaximized ni el fullscreen me funcionan, porque lo que intento hacer es que se adapten todo dependiendo de la resolución del usuario.

Comment: Hola Jeison. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Podrías añadir un poco más de información a tu pregunta cómo por ejemplo el código en el que intentas reproducir esto. Hay un método para PyQt5 llamado showMaximized que quizá te pueda servir. Te sugiero editar la pregunta y añadir más información para poder ayudarte y no te puntúen la pregunta de forma negativa. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, gracias, ya actualicé más la info